# Why std::shared_ptr considered to be "heavy" and "expensive", but std::array "same perfprmance as plain (c-style) arrays"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't quite understand why std::shared_ptr considered to be "heavy" and "expensive", but std::array "same performance as plain (c-style) arrays"? As in shared-ptr we have pointer and two counters: for shared and weak references. And in std::array we have pointer to a data and it's size(basically same as a pointer's counts in shared_ptr). Seems to be same overhead, though [everywhere](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) it's written that is has "performance and accessibility of a C-style array".

Comment: Why do you think `std::array` has the same overhead as `std::shared_ptr`? There's no dynamic allocation, no pointer, no run-time size, no ref count.

Comment: std::array doesn't have a pointer. It has an array. `sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N` (may be slightly bigger, but I've never encountered that in practice).

Comment: I think, you do not quite understand the `std::array` concept. There are no extra data members or run-time operations on `std::array` as compared to C-array, this is why it has exactly the same 'cost'.

Comment: @Justin I do not think there would be a case when size of `std::array<T, N>` would be any different from size of `T [N]`

Comment: @SergeyA I agree, but I think that the standard technically allows it

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has some overhead for maintaining atomic ref counter compared to raw pointer.

Comment: @Justin Not really.  the standard mandates that `std::array` is an aggregate, so there is really only one way to write it to have that qualifaction.

Comment: Have you read through the [`std::array` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: shared_ptr has a pointer to data, and another pointer to a control block, which contains two atomic reference counters. Accessing the counters requires a memory indirection, which can be costly as well if they are not in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And in std::array we have pointer to a data and it's size

A `std::array` has no need to store its size anywhere, much less store it in every object. For a given type, the value of `std::array::size()` is known at compile-time. *(Don't forget that `std::array<int, 2>` and `std::array<int, 3>` are different types.)*

```
template < class T, std::size_t N >
constexpr std::size_t std::array<T,N>::size()
{
    return N;
}
```

This is one possible implementation. It could have been made a `static` member function.

Answer (score 7):

> And in std::array we have pointer to a data and it's size(basically same as a pointer's counts in shared_ptr).

This is incorrect.  `std::array` is basically

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array
{
    T data[N];
};
```

There is no allocation, pointer, or extra size variable.  It just wraps a raw array and provides functions to make it a container.

`std::shared_ptr` on the other holds a pointer, and needs the pointed to object to be allocated dynamically.  It also needs to be reference counted, and that needs to be done in a thread safe manner which introduces a lot of overhead.

This is why `array` is a "zero cost abstraction" and `shared_ptr` is not.

Comment: Worth noting that `unique_ptr` is the zero-cost abstraction for memory management in C++.